# Is there any security issue to use this method of authenticating users in Laravel using the same login page?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, laravel-authentication

I'm a new Laravel Programmer and I tried to develop an web interface which uses the same login controller for two users which are from different tables. One user is Student and the other is Instructor. They are all routed to their intended page after login but I was wondering if there is any security issue to use this concept before I reach far? Or if there is any downside of using this logic or difficulties in implementing the logic or on trying securing the routes using middlewares?

**Login Controller**

```
 public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');


    if(Auth::guard("instructor")->attempt($credentials))
    {
        return redirect()->route("instructor");
    }

    else if(Auth::guard("student")->attempt($credentials))
    {
        return redirect()->route("dashboard");
    }

    else
    {
        return back()->with('status', 'The provided credentials do not match our records.');
    }
}
```

**Middlewares**

```
Route::middleware("auth:instructor")->group(function (){

Route::get("/instructorDashboard", [DashboardController::class, "instructor"])->name("instructor");
```

});

```
  Route::middleware("auth:student")->group(function () {

Route::get("/dashboard", [DashboardController::class, "student"])->name("dashboard");
```

});

**Dashboard Controller (They just return normal text, not view)**

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
```

{

```
public function student (Request $request)
{
    return "Your a Student";
}

public function instructor(Request $request)
{
    return "Your a Instructor";
}
```

}

**auth.php file**

```
 'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'student',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
 'guards' => [
    'student' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'students',
    ],

    'instructor' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'instructors',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],


],
'providers' => [
    'students' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
    ],
    'instructors' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Instructor::class
    ],
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel authentication is really well thought and implemented system. It has been battle tested and proven to work in production environment. What you are doing does not causes any security vunurabilities. But it might constraint on some business logic and it's understandable if you have such requirements. So your answer to questions is

**Is any security issue to use this concept?**

No there is no issue from any security side. Keep in mind that security is not only in one place. You might have really secured authentication system but you need to make sure other parts if application are well implemented too.

**Is there any downside of using this logic or difficulties in implementing the logic or on trying securing the routes using middlewares?**

There is no issue with securing routes with middleware. There are some potential downsides but software is all about compromisation. There is no downside of implementing this logic as long as you have solid robust archietecture and documentation for code flow/implementation.

If you are trying to find out vunurabilities in system. They will usually be
in custom authorization of user than that of laravel has provided. If you are really afraid about security reach out to github and look for any security bugs also read about [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) those are frequent bugs in applications.